# Где можно найти статистику использования версий Android в России

Tags: android

Может это вопрос не по адресу. Но знание основной используемой версии в конкретном регионе может повлиять на выбор минимальной версии SDK для вашего приложения. Меня не интересует статистика google play console для моего приложения. Меня интересует именно статистика версий Android на устройствах используемых пользователями в России.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к администрированию.

Comment: Этот вопрос имеет прямое отношение к администрированию собственных проектов и разработке в целом. Android dashboard может не соответствовать действительности в России. Подобная информация может повлиять на выбор минимальной версии SDK, а значить на использование функционала библиотеки совместимости, а не стандартных средств для современных версий Android.

Comment: если вы считаете, что вопросы типа «где найти то-то и то-то» стоит исключить из [вопросов, которые не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), или считаете что ваш вопрос по каким-то соображениям не относится к этому типу вопросов, вам стоит обсудить это на [meta].

Answer (score 1):

Моя статистика:

4.1 9.2%

4.2 13.2%

4.4 37%

5.0 15%

5.1 16%

6.0 5.5%

Comment: Источник бы указали.

Comment: Что за источник? Google Play console?